# Kernel density estimators in Bishop book unclear formulas

Tags: machine-learning

In [Bishop's book](https://moodle2.units.it/pluginfile.php/24254/mod_resource/content/1/Bishop_2009_Pattern_recognition_and_machine_learning.pdf) (Pattern recognition and machine learning, pag 122) there is an unclear passage for me in deriving certain formulas:

$E[K/N] = P$ and $var[K/N] = P(1-P)$

Considering binomial probability

$P(x=x) = \binom{N}{x} P^{x} \cdot (1 - P)^{(N-x)}$

I know that the expected value and variance is given by:

$E(X) = N \cdot x$

$var(X) = N \cdot x \cdot (1-x)$

As a first thing since Bishop refers to the fraction of points that fall in the bin, i.e., K/N, I would be tempted to substitute N for K/N, however, there are some steps (perhaps algebraic) that I am missing.

[image]